# Open Sublime from terminal app and get the result of the text added to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, command-line-interface

So what I am trying to do is a combination of a question I already asked on here:

"
I am making a command line app. I want to allow the user, when they are adding values for things in the terminal, to be able to add the value with their text editor. How does git achieve this?

I want to open their default editor, allow them to enter text, and when they save get the value and use that value for my app.
"

I figured out how to do this with vim:

```
var vim = require('child_process').spawn('vim', ['test.txt'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
vim.on('exit', process.exit);
```

But how would I do this with sublime? If I replace vim with subl, it opens sublime but then immediately returns the currently value of the file and does not wait until I have saved the file in sublime. Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to run `subl` with `-w` or `--wait` switch:

```
var subl = require('child_process').spawn('subl', ['-w', 'test.txt'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
subl.on('exit', process.exit);
```

Instead of hardcoding `subl` or `vim` in your application, I suggest you to use `EDITOR` environment variable if it is set:

```
if (process.env.EDITOR) {
  var editorArgs = process.env.EDITOR.split(' ');
  var editorExecutable = editorArgs.shift();
  var editor = require('child_process').spawn(editorExecutable, editorArgs.concat(['test.txt']), {stdio: 'inherit'});
  editor.on('exit', process.exit);
} else {
  // Run subl or vim
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! So simple. And thanks, now I also know how to get the EDITOR value from node :p